# After saying "X peut faire tous les Y qu'il veut", is it more common to omit "mais"?

Tags: grammaire

> Volkswagen peut tenir toutes les conférences de presse qu'elle veut, leurs excuses à la noix de dernière minute n'ont guère de valeur aux yeux des consommateurs.
>
> {or}: Volkswagen peut tenir toutes les conférences de presse qu'elle veut, **mais** leurs excuses à la noix de dernière minute n'ont guère de valeur aux yeux des consommateurs.

This is just a gut feeling on my part, but can I drop "mais" here? I'm translating what a person said in English into French, and in English, the use of "but" is necessary as a connector.

But what about in French? I wonder if some particular words in "X peut faire tous les Y qu'il veut" or the entire phrase makes it acceptable to omit "mais"?

Comment: Off topic but I would write "*[mais] **ses** excuses à la noix*", not *leurs*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Mais" is like "but": it is a mark of opposition between the implications of the two parts of the sentence:

> Je n'aime pas les légumes, mais comme c'est toi qui les a préparés je vais y goûter. / I don't like vegetables, but as you cooked them yourself I will give them a chance.

The first part explain that in a normal case the speaker would not eat these vegetables, the second one explains that the first part is not precisely exact, in particular for the present situation.

In your example there is no such contradiction, thus the use of "mais" is not correct. The sentence must be written without it. A correct construction with "mais" could be:

> Volkswagen peut tenir toutes les conférences de presse qu'elle veut, mais ne peut pas redonner confiance aux consommateurs.

Here there is an opposition between the first part (Wolkswagen can do things as they please) and the last part (Wolkswagen can't do the important things we are actually talking about). Note that it has a different implicit meaning than what you wanted to say:

- In your example it is implied that usually press conferences are a way to win the trust of consumers (but in this case it won't be enough).
- In my last example there is no such implication. The two things are considered different ones without any link.

Comment: +1 It is more like "Quelque soit le nombre de conférence que VW tiendra, leurs excuses n'auront guère de valeur".

Comment: Also to @Distic Hi. I'm a bit slow on the uptake here, but can't you say just as well: "Quel que soit le nombre de conférence que VW tiendra, elle ne pourra pas redonner confiance aux consommateurs."

Comment: @Alone-zee: yes, you can, except you have to write "conférence**s**", and using "elle" seems a bit weird (but not grammatically wrong).

Comment: I won't be that definite about the *mais* usage. There is an opposition between the large number of press conferences being help and expected to improve the company image and their poor perception among consumers.

Comment: Hi. Actually, what I wanted to ask was something else. Despite the fact that both sentences (your example and mine) can be paraphrased with "quel que soit le nombre de ...", I wonder why the use of "mais" is considered acceptable only for your example?

Comment: @Alone-zee: mine can't, it is more "même si VW peut X, VW ne peut pas Y" I'll try to edit so it is clearer

Answer (score 3):

*Mais* is fine here but you can drop it too. You might want to start a new sentence in that case or replace the comma by a semicolon though.

> *Volkswagen peut tenir toutes les conférences de presse qu'elle veut* (or *qu'il veut*)*; ses excuses à la noix de dernière minute n'ont guère de valeur aux yeux des consommateurs.*

Comment: I especially agree with your comment elsewhere (as I interpret it) that there’s perhaps enough of a connection between the numerous press conferences (during which, I assume, the said lame excuses were offered) & the public’s reaction to those excuses to argue that the public’s implied rejection of the excuses is in opposition to VW having offered them, thereby justifying a “mais.” cf:  “VW peut faire toutes les excuses qu'il veut (en tenant toutes les conferences de presse qu’elle veut), mais leurs/ses/ces excuses à la noix de dernière minute n'ont guère de valeur aux yeux des consommateurs.”